# Android json error

Tags: android, json

In my Android application I want to use google currency converter. Google currency converter outputs result in a json format like:

```
{lhs: "1 British pound",rhs: "1.6058 U.S. dollars",error: "",icc: true}
```

I used following code stub in my Android application to get the output from json

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonResult);
JSONObject json_data=null;
String currency01 = "";
String currency02 = "";
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    c1 = json_data.getString("lhs");
    c2 =json_data.getString("rhs");
    tv.append(c1+"\n\n");
    tv.append(c2);
}
```

but this doesn't give any result no errors also. Please help I'm stuck here how to read above json in Andoid.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't see **currency01** and **currency02** keys in json response..

Comment: I'm sorry for that mistake. but after changing also it doesn't work :(

Comment: Not to need any for loop because answer is in single format

Comment: Have you give internet permission ?

Comment: Yes I have given permission, and I also removed for loop but still having same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as you are not getting array its json object
I have tested using url http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1GBP=?USD

```
String currency01 = "";
String currency02 = "";
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
   currency01  = jObj.optString("lhs");
    currency02 =jObj .optString("rhs");
    tv.append(currency01 +"\n\n");
tv.append(currency02 "\n\n");
```

Comment: Ok! thank you very much. That was the error thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you to use Online JSON Validator http://jsonlint.com/

Using which you can identify issues in your JSON.

You can see below screenshot, I took your JSON value and put to validate which show me error.
[image: json validation error]

And here is another screenshot show successfully validated JSON
[image: json validation success]

You just need to put double quote surround to lhs, rhs, etc..

Comment: I think this maybe the error, but how can I correct it for Android ? please help

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonResult);
            JSONObject json_data=null;
            String c1 = "";
            String c2 = "";
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    c1 = json_data.getString("lhs");
                    c2 =json_data.getString("rhs");
                    tv.append(c1+"\n\n");
                    tv.append(c2"\n\n");
            }
```

Comment: I'm sorry for that mistake. but after changing also it doesn't work :(